# How to automatically make a copy of spreadsheet and rename it based on cell value (ex. name)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone help me figure this out please.

I need to automatically copy a spreadsheet (Contract) rename it based on the column value (customer name) and copy a row (customer details) into that newly created spreadsheet (details's sheet)

I was able to find a script to copy the file and rename it, but need help with copying the row,
and also if possible someone can help me with this existing script, if possible instead of clicking on the menu to run the script, have it run automatically whenever the new row is added.

Thank you in advance.

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Options')
.addItem('Generate Proposal','copyfilefromsource')
.addToUi();
}
function copyfilefromsource() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

var sheet_merge = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Customers");
var last_row = sheet_merge.getLastRow();

var name = null;
var phone = null;
var date = null;
var dest_folder = null;
var sheets_created = 0;
var new_file = null;
var source_file = null;
var lead = null;
var range = sheet_merge.getRange(1, 1, last_row, 30);
var temp = null;

source_file = DriveApp.getFileById('1XotVWkmjyi8OBRGy6N6mosPf16YwvozfKYxums_oMJ'); //gets the source file to copy
dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('17aawdMFOvF4clNcjA_JeK2v2Q9_VJnE'); //gets the ID of the folder to place the copied files into

if (last_row <= 1) {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No rows to process!");
return
}
for (var i = 2; i <= last_row; i++) { // loop to go down evenery row from 2 until the endLogger.log( cell.getA1Notation() );
if (range.getCell(i, 30).getValue() == '') { //makes sure there is nothing in the column, i.e. can run the script with some students already been processed if it fails half way through.

name = range.getCell(i, 3).getValue(); //gets first name from the sheet
event_date = range.getCell(i, 6).getValue(); //gets event date from the sheet
phone = range.getCell(i, 5).getValue(); //gets phone from the sheet
lead = range.getCell(i,1).getValue(); //gets lead link
new_file = source_file.makeCopy(name + " - " + phone + " - " + event_date, dest_folder);

//Add the details that the process has worked
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,1).setValue('=HYPERLINK("' + new_file.getUrl() +'/","Lead")');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,30).setValue(new_file.getId());
sheets_created++; // add to files created
}
}
ui.alert(sheets_created + " files were created!")
}

function testFolder(folderName){
var exist = true;
try{var testFolder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName)}
catch(err){exist=false}
return exist;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are using without personal information in it (dummy data)? Is this script as copied or has it been adapted to your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I'll at least start you out with your solution, and then I'll explain the next steps you should take. The below method will convert your row into an array, which you can manipulate as necessary.

```
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YOUR SHEET NAME')
let sheetData = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
//Assuming that the data you want to copy is being added to the last row
let row = sheetData[ss.getLastRow()]
```

From there, you can choose each index in the row array, and place that specific piece of data wherever you want on the new sheet you create, as long as you specify the range. For example, if you want to take the 4th index of the row array and want to paste it to cell D43 of a different sheet, you would do:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TARGET SHEET').getRange('D43').setValue(row[3])
```